# Is it possible to embed MicroPython into a CPython application?

Tags: micropython

Does the memory layout different a lot? Is it difficult to share object between CPython and MicroPython?

The backgroubd is that I want to use Python like LUA. To use a full CPython `eval()` or `exec()` is too dangerious, I hope that I can have a simplified version of Python, which is sandboxed and not have access to my operating system's syscall.

Comment: Your best place for an answer to this will be https://forum.micropython.org/

Answer (score 0):

CPython and MicroPython (and many other implementations for that matter) don't share any implementation details, so passing objects from one to the other requires translation of the types in C. And I think the aspect of sandboxing is rather orthogonal to which Python version you use, that is micropython is written in C just like CPython so to sandbox that and avoid access to whatever functionality, you'll need external components or other measures to support that. For example MicroPython also has exec/eval, if you don't want that you could exclude them from being compiled into the executable for instance, as you would for CPython.

Comment: And, on the other hand, if you do want the `exec` but don't want it to be dangerous (e.g by possibly calling `os system`) then you can disable the `os` module. Generally, using MicroPython you can achieve this type of sandbox.